# MassTransit stop consuming messages from queue after reach MaxConcurrentCalls on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-worker-roles, masstransit

I'm trying to use Masstransit with Autofac and Azure Service Bus running on a Azure WorkerRole, everything goes fine until the MaxConcurrentCalls is reached, than all published events are not consumed.

Here is my EntryPoint

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly ManualResetEvent runCompleteEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private IBusControl _bus;
    private IContainer _container;

    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("POC is running");

        try
        {
            this.RunAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.runCompleteEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureServiceBusConnectionString");
        string queue = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureServiceBusQueue");

        bool result = base.OnStart();

        if (result)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterType<InMemorySagaRepository<PocSaga>>().As<ISagaRepository<PocSaga>>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterStateMachineSagas(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.Register(c => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc =>
            {
                var serviceUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureSbNamespace"), CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureSbPath"));
                sbc.UseLog4Net();

                var host = sbc.Host(serviceUri, h =>
                {
                    h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureSbKeyName"), CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureSbSharedAccessKey"), TimeSpan.FromDays(1), TokenScope.Namespace);
                });

                sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceQueueName"), e =>
                {
                    e.LoadFrom(c);
                    e.RequiresSession = true;
                    e.LoadStateMachineSagas(c);
                    e.MaxConcurrentCalls = 8;
                    e.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = false;
                });
            }))
            .SingleInstance()
            .As<IBusControl>()
            .As<IBus>();

            _container = builder.Build();

            Trace.TraceInformation("POC has been started");

            var bc = _container.Resolve<IBusControl>();
            bc.Start();

            Trace.TraceInformation("Masstransit has been started");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("POC is stopping");

        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        this.runCompleteEvent.WaitOne();

        var bc = _container.Resolve<IBusControl>();
        bc.Stop();

        base.OnStop();

        Trace.TraceInformation("POC has stopped");
    }

    private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var bc = _container.Resolve<IBusControl>();
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working - Publishing a new IStartPocMessage - {0}",id);
            await bc.Publish<StartPocSagaMessage>(new { CorrelationId = id });
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            await bc.Publish<LoopMessage>(new { CorrelationId = id });
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            await bc.Publish<LoopMessage>(new { CorrelationId = id });
            await Task.Delay(30000);
        }
    }
}
```

And the SAGA

```
public class PocStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<PocSaga>
{
    public PocStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Event(() => StartSaga);
        Event(() => LoopMessageEvent);

        Initially(
            When(StartSaga)
            .Then(context => {
                Trace.TraceInformation("[SAGA] StartSaga recebido, saga criada e mudandando estado para Active - {0}",context.Data.CorrelationId);
                Trace.TraceInformation("[SAGA] [StartSaga] -- {0} ---- {1}", context.Instance.CorrelationId, context.Data.CorrelationId);
            })
            .TransitionTo(Active),
            When(LoopMessageEvent)
            .Then(context =>
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("[SAGA] - [Initially] LoopMessageEvent recebido - {0}", context.Data.CorrelationId);
            }).TransitionTo(Active)
            );
        WhenEnter(Active,
            x => x.Then(context => Trace.WriteLine("[SAGA] Entering Active State"))
            );
        WhenEnter(Processing,
            x => x.
            Then(context => Trace.WriteLine("[SAGA] Entering Processing"))
            );

        During(Active,
            When(LoopMessageEvent)
            .Then(context => Trace.TraceInformation("[SAGA] LoopScheduleMessage recebido, transicionando para Processing - {0}", context.Data.CorrelationId))
            .TransitionTo(Processing)
            );

        During(Processing,
            When(LoopMessageEvent)
            .Then(context => Trace.TraceInformation("[SAGA] During Processing - LoopMessageReceived, Finishing()", context.Data.CorrelationId))
            .Finalize()
            );

        SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
    }

    public State Active { get; private set; }
    public State Processing { get; private set; }


    public Event<StartPocSagaMessage> StartSaga { get; private set; }
    public Event<LoopMessage> LoopMessageEvent { get; private set; }

}

public class LoopMessage : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public LoopMessage(Guid jobId)
    {
        CorrelationId = jobId;
        JobId = jobId;
    }

    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

}

public class StartPocSagaMessage : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public StartPocSagaMessage(Guid jobId)
    {
        CorrelationId = jobId;
        JobId = jobId;
    }

    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public interface IStartPocMessage
{
    Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class PocSaga : SagaStateMachineInstance
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public State CurrentState { get; set; }
    public Guid? ExpirationId { get; set; }
}
```

After 8 sagas were started, it stops to consume new messages. I simply don't know why it is happening.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've got the same result without using Autofac.

Comment: Does your consumer ever finish? It seems like it isn't returning, freeing up a slot for the next consumer.

Comment: Yes, the consumer is finished. I manage to narrow it down to the following scenario, it only happens when 
`e.RequiresSession = true;`
It seems something with related to that configuration. I've changed to not use Session and it started to work.